# index out of bounds; value 1 out of bound 0 in matlab

Tags: matlab, aes

"hi
This program in Matlab read two input file (file.txt and file2.txt) which has 80000 random number. when I execute the following program It has error(index out of bounds; value 1 out of bound 0 in Matlab). I am unable to fix this error. kindly I need i your help."

```
clear all
close all
rel=textread('file.txt');
ct=textread('file2.txt');
bh0=zeros(256,20000);  
bh1=zeros(256,20000);
Te2=[99 124 119 123 242 107 111 197];
for i=1:20000

    m(i)=bitxor(ct(16*(i-1)+1),180); 
    if m(i)==Te2(1)|m(i)==Te2(2)|m(i)==Te2(3)|m(i)==Te2(4)|m(i)==Te2(5)|m(i)==Te2(6)|m(i)==Te2(7)|m(i)==Te2(8)
        bh0(m(i)+1,i)=rel(1+4*(i-1));
    else   
        bh1(m(i)+1,i)=rel(1+4*(i-1));
    end
end

for k=1:256
    counter=1;
    for i=1:20000
        if bh0(k,i)~=0
            bh0_final(k,counter)=bh0(k,i);
            counter=counter+1;
        end
    end
end
for k=1:256
    counter=1;
    for i=1:20000
        if bh1(k,i)~=0
            bh1_final(k,counter)=bh1(k,i);
            counter=counter+1;
        end
    end
end

for i=1:20000
    ciphertext0(i)=ct(16*(i-1)+1);
    reload0(i)=rel(1+4*(i-1));
end
sum_c0=zeros(20000,256);
for i=1:20000
    for j=1:256
        if ciphertext0(i)==j
            sum_c0(i,j)=reload0(i);
        end
    end
end

counterr=zeros(1,256);
summ=zeros(1,256);
for i=1:20000
    for k=1:256
        if sum_c0(i,k)~=0
        counterr(k)=counterr(k)+1;
        summ(k)=summ(k)+sum_c0(i,k);
        end
    end
end
for k=1:256
    mean(k)=summ(k)/counterr(k);
end
var=zeros(1,256);
for i=1:20000
    for k=1:256
        if sum_c0(i,k)~=0
            var(k)=((sum_c0(i,k)-mean(k))^2)/counterr(k);
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Actually read the full error and think about what it says. Matlab's error messages are very useful. It will tell you which statement is causing the error, which makes it much easier to solve the problem.

Comment: Without reading the code, could the problem be this of empty matrices? That you have a 0-by-1 matrix instead of a 1-by-0 matrix or something like that? Apart from this it is actually quite hard to tell why you get an out of bounds error. May I suggest the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html)?

Answer (score 0):

by just reading the code, i suspect something happens in this line

```
m(i)=bitxor(ct(16*(i-1)+1),180);
```

ct should have a length 80000 so for i=lets say 20000 it checks at ct(19999*16 +1) --out of bounds